# Limit size of email address?

Tags: email

I create an email address as per spec. I get a huge email address

```
emailreceiverservice@4-1hfmpkbetc58ltv1h1zyf4hqmnc0c6ucc653lk76ptyb4d10vl.i-hqfceak.il.apex.salesforce.com
```

Is there any way to get a smaller email address?

A related question:
I have a custom email setting which when I enter this email address it gets cropped. 
Is there anyway to specify the length for an email field?

I know I could do this by using String type instead of email type.  I just wanted to check is there a more elegant solution.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean you generated an email address for Email Services and this is the result?

Comment: As stupid as it sounds - can't you contact your email server admin and ask him to set up autoforwarding from "human friendly address" to "SF generated email"?

Comment: This has bitten me as well - maximum length for a User's Email is 80 characters... yet Email Services can have 100+ character addresses :( +1

Comment: @user31 that's the crux of the issue. Where you able to get the Email service to generate a smaller field?

Comment: If by chance your org instance gets assigned a shorter Email Services alias, you can delete and recreate the address and luck into one < 80 characters. I ended up using [https://ifttt.com/](https://ifttt.com/) to get around it for a bit.

Answer (score 1):

Currently you don't have an control over the email services receiver addresses.  You'll need to accomodate the additional length in your settings.

I wasn't aware there was a limit to email field length, that is a pain.  Given that custom settings are only accessed by administrators I think giving up the additional validation constraints for email fields in favor of the additional space for a text field is a pretty reasonable design decision.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you use Google Apps within your company, but one of the things I did to shorten those email addresses up was create a group within Google Apps and have all emails to that group sent to the Salesforce generated email address.

Most email platforms should let you do something similar I would think.

Answer (score 0):

I'm still running into this issue in 2020 with Lighting: Salesforce email services creates email addresses larger than 80 characters, but contacts are limited to 80 characters or less.

I ended up creating a distribution group in Exchange as a work around - what a shame.

Upvote Salesforce Idea Exchange here:

https://success.salesforce.com/ideaview?id=08730000000BpGHAA0